# Selenium cannot interact with an accordion-item

Tags: python, reactjs, selenium-webdriver, testing, automation

I've been trying to get an autmation test running for a site, I can successfully log in and land at the dashboard. However when trying to click on a module from a sidebar menu, selenium is not able to interact with it. Here is the html of[The highlighted part is the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xZzH.png) the side menu.[Here is the whole screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12FOR.png)

The front-end is done with react, the exception I'm getting is:
"selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable"

I've tried different techniques, like Xpath, full Xpath, class name.

As far as I can tell, selenium can find the element but the "click()" function is not working.
Any help/advice would be humbly appreciated, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well ElementNotInteractableException exception appears, when element is displaying but it is clear enough to be interacted, either it is cutted off (which is most possible) or action on DOM is not added.
It would be better, if you can share whole screen image or URL.
meanwhile, you can do two things...

1. Add a wait, where you have to check that `element_to_be_clickable`
2. Scroll to that element and then perform action.

Comment: I've already tried the two things you suggested, both yield the same results. I've now included the whole screen image you requested.

Comment: Can you share URL as well, so that I can look into it? also try with two waits i.e. first element_to_be visible and then element_to_be_clickable

Comment: I cannot share URL because of company policy unfortunately

Comment: I tried using two waits, still not interactable, can I implement nested waits?